# Django - Creating model fields from list with for loop

Tags: python, django

I have a long list of 100 labels I need my model to have as fields and to also call in succession to access them in other parts of code.  I am going to need to modify them in the future so I would like to be able to do it in one place.  Is there a simple way to do this. For example:

```
labels = ['height', 'weight', 'age']
```

In models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    for label in labels:
        label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Would the above be equal to :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    height = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: what does "to also call in succession to access them in other parts of code" mean? Does every model have 100 labels? How often are the labels changing?

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DevModelCreation

Comment: So the one model will have 100 different fields then I want to be able to call all those fields.  For example: [MyModel.field for field in labels].

Comment: No, that code is not equivalent. Strings (fortunately) don't automatically convert to symbols

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265402/adding-class-attributes-using-a-for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django models have an `add_to_class` method which adds a field (or any attribute, really) to a class. The syntax is `MyModel.add_to_class(name, value)`. The resulting code would be:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

for label in labels:
    MyModel.add_to_class(label, models.CharField(max_length=255))
```

Internally, this will call the `contribute_to_class` method on the value passed, if that method exists. Static attributes are added to the class as-is, but fields have this method and all subsequent processing will ensue.

Comment: When would be the best time to call the for loop, not in the model class?  In the models.py file?  Won't that cause some problems with migrations?

Comment: @SimpleSyrup Just after the model definition. It won't cause problems with syncdb/migrations, as the model and its fields are fully defined after the class is imported.

Comment: I see.  Since python looks at the entire file.  Thanks for the tips.  This solved my dilema.

Comment: Is this considered the most "Pythonic" way to write the code if a Model class contains 20+ attributes?

Answer (score 4):

Using `locals()` should work here:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    for label in labels:
        locals()[label] = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    del locals()['label']
```

Comment: So this is python.  making label a local variable for the class.  Right?

Comment: Oops, it'll actually be exposed as a property at `MyClass.label`. You'll want to add a `del locals()['label']` after that loop to prevent that

Comment: I don't understand after the entire loop or in the loop?  Wouldn't I want it exposed as that is the behavior that django has by default?  Or would it actually try to pull it from the class as opposed to the db?

Comment: Without that delete, `MyModel.label == 'age'`, which is not useful to anyone