# Setting class attributes using a loop inside constructor

Tags: python, class, constructor

I have a simple class (Python 3.6):

```py
class MyClass:
    id: int
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
```

I wish to set the class attributes when instantiating using a loop, something like:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        for attr in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            # put something in "self.attr", e.g. something like: self.attr = 1
    id: int
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
```

Why would I want to do this?

1. the list is long
2. I'm instantiating *some* of the values using an external nested dictionary `d` which has `id` as keys and a `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` as value

So really this would look like:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, id, d):
        self.id = id
        for attr in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            # put d[id][attr] in "self.attr", e.g. something like: self.attr = d[id][attr]
    id: int
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
```

[Adding class attributes using a for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265402/adding-class-attributes-using-a-for-loop-in-python)  is a similar question, but not identical; I'm specifically interested in looping over attributes when instantiating the class, i.e. in the `__init()__` constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using setattr() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561174/using-setattr-in-python)

Comment: If you're can move to 3.7+, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) on `self`:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, id, d):
        self.id = id
        for attr in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            setattr(self, attr, d[id][attr])


d = {"123": {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}}
instance = MyClass("123", d)

print(instance.a)
print(instance.b)
print(instance.c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put the attributes that you want to set in a class variable and then loop through them with `setattr`:

```
class Potato:

    _attributes = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    def __init__(self, id, d):
        for attribute in _attributes:
            setattr(self, attribute, d[id][attribute])
```